# Slow IOUtils.copy() performance when uploading files through commons-fileupload

Tags: spring-boot, ubuntu-18.04, java-11, apache-commons-fileupload, apache-commons-io

In one of my Spring Boot Controllers I receive file uploads (up to 500 MB) like this:

```
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);

while (iter.hasNext()) {
    FileItemStream item = iter.next();

    if (item.isFormField()) {
    } else {
        try (InputStream in = item.openStream(); OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("path-to-file")) {
            IOUtils.copy(in, out);
        }
    }
}
```

The file is saved in the local file system of an Ubuntu 18.04, and it works well.

The problem is that the upload speed is ridiculously slow, less than 2 MB/s in average. Also there is cpu load of around 20% while the upload is happening.

When I copy a file with scp to the same box, I max out at my internet connection's upload of 50 Mbit.

Why is this file upload so slow?

In fact I see no speed improvement compared to my initial implementation using Spring's MultipartFile-based upload mechanism (apart of not getting and OOM errors anymore since I moved to `commons-fileupload`)

Comment: To copy an `InputStream` to an `OutputStream`, you can use `in.transferTo(out)` (since Java 9). Since your target is a local file, you can use the even simpler `Files.copy(in, Paths.get("path-to-file"));` (since Java 7). The advantage of not using a 3rd party library is that you don’t need to reason about what this 3rd party library probably does in additional to the straight-forward copy operation. When it’s still slow, you know that the copy method is not cause of the problem. By the way, do you mean *download* (the usual name for transferring to a local file)?

Comment: Thanks I for your comment I will try it out later and give feedback. I write _upload_ because it's about large file uploads from client browsers towards my web application.

Comment: I tried Files.copy() in the same environment than my question is about. It looks like it's faster, I had about half of the time of the upload a speed of 4MB, which is about double more than with IOUtils.copy() (Note that yesterday I wrote 2Mbit which was meant to be 2MB)

Comment: And what about the `scp` number? Was it MBit or MB?

Comment: `scp` was around 6MB/s.